# submit html form using php but stay on same page

Tags: php, html

I have a simple HTML form, for example:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="first_name" id="firstName">
<label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="last_name" id="lastName">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

using a PHP script I called insert.php:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO database VALUES ('$firstName','$lastName)";

if(mysqli_query($Conn,$sql)){
    echo "<h3>data stored in database successfully.</h3>";
}   else{
    echo mysqli_error($Conn);
}
```

I add the input from the form to a SQL database. Obviously, after the submit button is pressed, the browser ends up on insert.php with the success message printed(action="insert.php"). I want to know how can I keep the browser on the form page and print the success/error message somewhere on the same page.

Comment: use javascript to send it via ajax

Comment: any way without using js? or would the only way be to put the insert script on the form page?

Comment: ......nope.....

Comment: No need for AJAX, just in your `insert.php` after all use redirect to the form. You can also handle the form and submitting in one script, that way you can pre-fill the form with previously sent data. The ocean of possibilities, insert the coin, choose the flavor.

Answer (score 2):

Either use Ajax to do the submission, or have your insert.php code in your main script - change your form to submit to the same page it appears on by simply removing the `action=""` attribute.

Check if the form has been submitted - e.g. by looking for the submit button having been pressed in the `$_REQUEST` or `$_POST` arrays, then do the insert.

Or a third option - in your insert.php redirect the user back to where they came from after processing.

Have a read up on why you shouldn't write user-submitted data straight to your database - and consider using mysqli_real_escape_string or parameterised queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can record the message in one session and show the message after redirecting to the previous page.

- session method:

```
start_session();
public function message($msg = ""){
            if (!empty($msg)) {
                $_SESSION['message'] = $msg;
            } elseif (isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
                // then this is "get message"
                $this->message = $_SESSION['message'];
                return $this->message;
            }
        }
```

- redirect method:

```
function redirect_to($new_link){
        header("Location: " . $new_link);
        exit;
    }
```

- php code(save message and redirect back):

```
if ($Variable->create()) {
        $session->message("New user created...");
        redirect_to("URL");
      }
```